# Excel Call text in a cell as a factor in a formula

Tags: string, excel, text, countif

I have a need to count cells with a particular string of text.  I have a list of each string of text to be counted.

I am forming a query using CountIf in the form:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4929,"String")
```

where every occurrence of 'String' is counted and output.

I would like to show the counts for each string of text in a column alongside the String.  I have created a column with one string per cell.

What I would love to be able to do is call the string in the cell into the CountIf function, sort of like:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4929, "Whatever's in the column to the left of this output cell")
```

But I can't work it out.  Am looking and will update here IMMEDIATELY if I work it out.

EDIT:
DONE!

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4929,INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `=COUNTIF(C1:C4929,"="&D1)` copied down from E1, where ColumnD contains your strings.

Comment: You can also normally use just `=COUNTIF(C:C,D1)`

Comment: Actually, that won't work because it's a horrific sheet generated by a website forms tool (actually a voter registration tool) and there is no key of that sort.  That's what I tried first.  I think, unfortunately, that the really inelegant indirect route might be best.  I am happy to be corrected!